# How can sort DataSeries based values and index?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, series

I have a dataseries (mean_ratings) like below:

```
A. Morin                  39203.340909
AMMA                      53476.250000
Acalli                    43798.333333
Adi                       41277.500000
Aequare (Gianduja)        45185.000000
                              ...     
Zokoko                    44615.000000
Zotter                    46138.326531
hello cocoa               26162.333333
hexx                      35043.333333
twenty-four blackbirds    36877.666667
```

I sort this series with this code:

```
best_ratings = mean_ratings.sort_values(0,ascending=False) 

Idilio (Felchlin)                  70040.000000
Dole (Guittard)                    65662.500000
Chocola'te                         64725.000000
Christopher Morel (Felchlin)       63787.500000
Madecasse (Cinagra)                62454.166667
Salgado                            61285.000000
Compania de Chocolate (Salgado)    61285.000000
Chloe Chocolat                     61285.000000
Oialla by Bojessen (Malmo)         61285.000000
Rozsavolgyi                        61285.000000
```

But I want to sort this, first based on values , and then for equal values based on alphabetic indexes.
How can I do this simultaneously?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `kind='mergesort'` on the second sort. Something like:

```
df.sort_index().sort_values(0, ascending=False, kind='mergesort')
```

Comment: I do this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry wrong order! I updated my answer. Can you check it please. Please provide a relevant sample.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `.sort_values()` a *list* of the column names you wish to sort by to sort at multiple levels!

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar':[2,1,4,3]})
>>> df
  foo  bar
0   a    2
1   a    1
2   b    4
3   c    3
>>> df.sort_values(["foo", "bar"])
  foo  bar
1   a    1
0   a    2
2   b    4
3   c    3
>>> df.sort_values(["bar", "foo"])
  foo  bar
1   a    1
0   a    2
3   c    3
2   b    4
```

Comment: It seems the first column is the index.

Comment: oh, I'd misread a confusing Question - it should just be sorted in two rounds

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but I want to sort simultaneously based on index, not two columns.

Comment: @AmirhosseinZohoorian. Use the `kind` parameter of `sort_index` to use a stable algorithm.

Comment: are the names the index? you could `.reset_index()` 'em to a new column first too